# Regex with sed to search in files

Tags: regex, linux

I want to search recursiv in files for a given pattern and replace them. The search is for a string like "['DB']['1']['HOST'] = 'localhost'". If testing the regex the following doesn't print anything. Can't see an error in this regex? Could anyone help?

```
sed -n '/\[\'HOST\'\]\s?=\s?(?:\'|")(.+)(?:\'|")/p' /path/to/file
```

Comment: The regex is not a valid POSIX pattern. Remove `?:` and use `-E` option. Use `\x27` instead of `\'`.

Comment: Note that grep is better suited than sed if you only want to filter lines of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups. Besides, you have not specified the `-E` option and the pattern is parsed as a BRE POSIX pattern where the capturing parentheses should be escaped. Also, the single quotes cannot be escaped to be used in a sed regex pattern, use `\x27` instead.

Use

```
sed -En '/\[\x27HOST\x27\]\s?=\s?[\x27"][^\x27"]+[\x27"]/p'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/6jbAVi):

```
s="a string like ['DB']['1']['HOST'] = 'localhost'."
sed -En '/\[\x27HOST\x27\]\s?=\s?[\x27"][^\x27"]+[\x27"]/p' <<< "$s"
```

Besides, instead of `\s`, it might be a good idea to use `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Great, perfectly working. May I ask you what the advantage is to replace the \s?

Comment: @heppi75 Better portability across tools using POSIX regex. `[:space:]` matches whitespace chars when used in POSIX regex bracket expressions.